# Does the TDRS user segment ever provide network functionality beyond being a "customer"?

Tags: nasa, data-transmission, tdrss

Celestrak's NORAD Two-Line Element Sets [Current Data TLE page](https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/) has many pre-defined categories for quick access for groups of spacecraft that share similar characteristics.

I clicked on the `Tracking and Data Relay Satellite System (TDRSS)` option, and many spacecraft named "TDRS" are listed:

```
TDRS 3, TDRS 5, TDRS 6, TDRS 7, TDRS 8, TDRS 9, TDRS 10, TDRS 11, TDRS 12
```

<s>Neither the names `TDRS-M` nor [`TDRS-13`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TDRS-M) appear yet.</s> [TDRS-13 has now "graduated" from TDRS school!](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/26268/12102)

There are many more included as well:

```
AIM, AQUA, AURA, FGRST (GLAST), GPM-CORE, HST, ISS (ZARYA), JPSS-1, LANDSAT 7, MMS 1, 
MMS 2, MMS 3, MMS 4, SORCE, SWIFT, TERRA, THEMIS A, THEMIS D, THEMIS E, TIMED, WISE
```

These *look like* spacecraft that use the TDRS satellites, and I'm guessing that they make up the [User Segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracking_and_Data_Relay_Satellite_System#User_segment) of the [Tracking and Data Relay Satellite System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracking_and_Data_Relay_Satellite_System) (TDRS).

**Question:** Does the user segment behave as simply TDRS "customers", or do they contribute in some way to the function? For example, is TDRS traffic ever *routed through* a user segment member, or buffered or stored there for later transmission? Since one of the user segments `ISS (ZARYA)` is manned at all times, are there any special TDRS management functions performed there by the ISS crew?

Comment: I'm trying to research this question [i.e. find a reference in the open lit] but I want to make sure I understand what you are asking.  Are you asking if user spacecraft ever function as part of the Space Network by channeling traffic to or from a TDRS to another user spacecraft?  IE the normal path is Ground <-> TDRS <-> user, you are asking if a path of Ground <-> TDRS <-> user1 <-> user2 is ever used?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I can't distinguish clearly enough between those two options. If I said "does a member of the user segment ever touch or handle or relay or store another user member's traffic?" would that be at all clearer?

Comment: I think so, but I'm abandoning my effort because I think the question is really not answerable, at least without a huge research effort.  I'm pretty sure the answer is no for NASA, but without checking every single spacecraft... And who knows what the DOD gets up to.

Comment: @OrganicMarble okay I'll let it finish one cycle once around the Earth, and if there's no activity I will probably either delete or revise.

Comment: I can tell you that THEMIS is strictly a TDRSS customer, and we are never used as a relay for other missions or customers.   Onboard storage and transmitter power are highly constrained resources, and the flight software would have to be designed and tested from the get-go to implement relay capabilities.  I can't speak for the other missions you listed, but I would be extremely surprised if these considerations didn't apply to them as well.

Comment: @JimLewis this is what I would expect, but it seems like a big effort to "prove a negative" for every customer.