# Has TDRS-13 officially graduated from "TDRS school" (entered into service)?

Tags: nasa, data-transmission, tdrss

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TDRS-M):

> TDRS-M, **to be renamed TDRS-13 upon entry into service**, is an American communications satellite operated by NASA as part of the Tracking and Data Relay Satellite System. The thirteenth Tracking and Data Relay Satellite, it is the third and final third-generation spacecraft to be launched, following the 2014 launch of TDRS-L. (emphasis added)

In this [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/26255/12102) I've suggested that this may have come to pass, as it is named `TDRS-13` in the TLE I downloaded today from Celestrak.

However, it does not show up in thier Tracking and Data Relay Satellite System (TDRSS) option on Celestrak's NORAD Two-Line Element Sets [Current Data TLE page](https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/), on which only the following spacecraft which have TDRS in their name are found:

```
TDRS 3, TDRS 5, TDRS 6, TDRS 7, TDRS 8, TDRS 9, TDRS 10, TDRS 11, TDRS 12
```

Has TDRS-13 officially entered into service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, "NASA has begun operating it" as of Feb. 15th.

> Following its August launch and a five-month period of in-orbit
>   testing, the third-generation Tracking and Data Relay Satellite
>   (TDRS), referred to as TDRS-M until this important milestone, was
>   renamed TDRS-13, becoming the tenth operational satellite in the
>   geosynchronous, space-based fleet.

[source](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2018/last-nasa-communications-satellite-of-its-kind-joins-fleet)

Comment: Thank you for the speedy confirmation. I've updated that [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/26255/12102) to reflect the good news.